# iOS Unit testing with specta on AWS device farm

Tags: ios, unit-testing, kif, aws-device-farm, specta

I'm using today [specta](https://github.com/specta/specta) to do unit tests.
I'm want to start using AWS device farm but when I try to upload the xctest folder it doesn't work.
My first fought it that it becouse I'm using specta. 
Do you know if this might be the problem?
Maybe someone know if it is possible to convert all my test to KIF that is supported by amazon?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a member of the AWS Device Farm team. 
We have not officially tested Specta on device farm. However, if Specta supports or is based off XCTest/XCTest UI or KIF and if all the dependencies can be bundled in the test package as per our instructions I have no strong reason right now to believe on why it would not run on device farm.

Having said that our instructions for packaging for XCTest, XCTest UI and KIF based tests are different and I would make sure that the appropriate instructions were followed depending on what Specta is based on and then run it against the corresponding test on device farm.

Hope that answers your question.